# win server 2008 r2 sp1 account login stuck at "Setting up personalized settings for: Windows Desktop Update"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Last night I installed sp1 onto this server. It took forever and when it finished it wanted to reboot. I said okay and when it came back up I logged in with my domain account and the login is stuck on "Setting up personalized settings for: Windows Desktop Update". I logged out of my account and tried the domain administrator. Same thing. Even left it overnight just hoping that it was being slow.

When I ended the task for the personalized settings the machine just sat there and didn't finish booting.

This machine hosts our dynamics database and a fileshare. Both of which are working fine for the users this morning. It's just the local machine login that seems to be affected here.

What can I do to resolve this?  Just to clarify here i've not actually completed a reboot since the service pack was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ending the task, you could try starting explorer from task manager (File... New Task (Run) and enter **explorer** in the box.

Comment: Hi Chris, I stopped the "personalized settings" task and it brought down explorer with it. So I ran a new explorer process as you suggested. This just resulted in the personalized settings task trying to run again and getting stuck.  I was able to get services.msc to run for me and I used that to stop the Windows Update service. I then killed the personalized settings task once more and started a new explorer process. This time, it worked. I guess something in the windows update service running was causing my issues.  Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: HTH. Thanks for adding the extra detail - you never know when someone will need to know it!

Answer (score -1):

Try to Disable the network card if its on VM and login with Local Admin and Follow the steps suggested by Chris .Then Do Run chkdsk /r which will clear any hard disk related issues. Hope this helps.